# Page not showned in multi page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I created a multipage(data-role="page") html. In **page1**  i have username field when initially
 fill the username it stores in **localstorage** and  **redirects to page2**. It is working fine again open the app to check localstorage is present or not until **hide** the **page1** in **pagebeforeshow** event so the problem occurs here the **page2** is **not created**. How to solve this one. Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mL8yLu2/6/)

***Note** In fiddle type the text and submit then refresh the page.
Html is like:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>page 1 from html</h1>
      <a >Go</a>

    </div><!-- /header -->   
      <div data-role="content">
          <label>Type text to store in LocalStoreage</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" />
          <button id="sub">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
      <a href="#page1">Back</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->  
      <div data-role="content">
          <p> Hi i am second page</p>
      </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->
```

script is:

```
 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#page1",function(){
    $("#page1").hide();
    var locStorage = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    //alert(locStorage);
    if(locStorage){
         $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    }else{
        $("#page1").show();
    }
});

    $(document).on("click","#sub",function(){
       // alert( $("#name").val());
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", $("#name").val());
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    });
```

When comment `$("#page1").hide();` this line the **page1 shows** after that only navigate to **page2** i ***don't want to show the page1 when localstorage is available***.

**EDIT :** Set `$.mobile.autoInitialize = false;` before loading jquery mobile even though the page1 loads for few seconds.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792660/how-to-decide-which-page-to-load-first-on-jquery-mobile) might help.

Comment: @MysticMagic thank you for your reply http://jsfiddle.net/5mL8yLu2/7/ now also load the page1 for few seconds and after that redirect to page 2

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 windows.location.href="index.html#page2"
```

> OR

```
windows.location.href="#page2"
```

instead of

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
```

So you can try this code,

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#page1",function(){
var locStorage = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
//alert(locStorage);
if(locStorage!=null){
     windows.location.href="#page2";
}
else{
     windows.location.href="#page1";
}
});

$(document).on("click","#sub",function(){
   // alert( $("#name").val());
localStorage.setItem("lastname", $("#name").val());
    windows.location.href="#page2"; 
});
```

Comment: can your provide some fiddle..because i tried in my app `windows.location.href="index.html#page2";` it doesn't go to page2